# What’s the meaning of ‘proudly’ in the context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "I reckon he had a pretty good idea we were going to try, and instead of stopping us, he just taught us enough to help. I don't think it was an accident he let me find out how the mirror worked. It's almost like he thought I had the right to face Voldemort if I could...."
>   "Yeah, Dumbledore's off his rocker, all right," said Ron **proudly**.
>   (Harry Potter)

What's the meaning of *proudly* in this context?

Comment: My soon took the HP books off to college, but my wife and I *think* Ron is proud because Dumbledore's madness reflects the trio's: "We're crazy just like Dumbledore!"

Comment: It’s been looked very awkward before I get you and your wife’s divine words. I’m very happy to meet who understands literatures.

Comment: I think this is Too Localised because I can't closevote it as General Reference. The meaning of *proudly* is easily obtained from a dictionary. The specific significance here is something for the reader to figure out in context. ELL is not Literary Criticism.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hmm, why *can't* we close as General Reference?

Comment: @WendiKidd: I *suppose* it must have been discussed in Meta - but if so, it passed me by. Presumably because we don't yet have a consensus over what counts as GR for non-native speakers. Lots of things that are "obvious" to Anglophones (or at least, dead easy to look up) might be somewhat opaque to people from a totally different cultural background. But to be honest,  I don't know why, and I don't know yet whether it bothers me or not.

Comment: The 'general reference' close reason is only enabled on a few sites, but even so, it tends to be way overused. This question, for example, is not general reference: the quote is puzzling precisely because the usage doesn't seem to match the definition of the word "proudly".

Comment: @Martha: I haven't read it, but given Harry Potter is a *children's* book, I doubt the word would be used in a particularly "puzzling" way, in context.

Comment: I agree with @FumbleFingers that this is at bottom a LitCrit question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A paragraph or two earlier comes this:

> "I always said he was off his rocker," said Ron, looking quite impressed at how crazy his hero was.

Ron is proud because, in his mind, Harry's musings have just *proven* his pronouncement about Dumbledore to be correct- Dumbledore *is* off his rocker.